# ng-options not correctly updating ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my code loads everything works as expectd,  the select box is shown and all thge options come from the `state.TRVs` I am passing into the directive.  And the value of `myConfig.myTime` is selected, however when i change the value the select box goes blank and myConfig.myTime is `undefined`. I am using AngularJS v1.2.28.

I have a directive here is the directive element in HTML:

```
<my-dir my-config="conf" time-range-values="state.TRVs"></my-dir>
```

The directive:

```
angular.
    module("myMod").
    directive("myDir", [
function () {
    "use strict";

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            myConfig: "=",
            timeRangeValues: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "my-temp"
   };
}]);
```

my-temp.html:

```
<select ng-model="myConfig.myTime"
ng-options="v as v for (k, v) in timeRangeValues track by v">
</select>
```

Comment: a jsFiddle or Plunkr goes a long way in helping us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `track by v` expression. From AngularJS [docs on `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-):

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.

I had the similar issue in my code just today, and it turned out that i did try to use both those things in one expression. Removing it helped.